# Is it safe to use an old mobile phone as modem / router for Wifi?

Tags: mobile-data, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering, router

(Related to [A phone as a home 4G modem/router?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/61910/336125))

I was wondering if it is **plausible** and **safe** to **keep an old phone charging all the time with a sim card** in order to use it as a **modem/router for Wifi**.

I thought about this idea in order to have a low-cost Wifi for an alarm system. However, my mother is afraid the mobile phone, if left all day charging and running, might explode and start a fire. Is it possible this would happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does mobile hotspot have security vulnerabilities in older phones?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209733/does-mobile-hotspot-have-security-vulnerabilities-in-older-phones)

Comment: I have seen a lot blown up batteries because of charging 24/7 but to my experience batteries usually do explode very very rarely. Usually such batteries are physically damaged.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I was more worried about physical safety (a fire hazard), rather than security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Interesting idea. Your mother's concerns are valid for the simple reason that it's not the designed usage to be on charge 24 by 7 (they are meant to be used in *mobile* mode). If you are comfortable with rooting a device, look for a device that supports *battery idle mode* and keep it on charge as [explained here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/223812/131553)

Comment: Further, in light of heating concerns, read this, if you plan to [use mobile phone without battery](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/174862/131553)